# I have created VM in Azure bastion, but I want to access VM through browser but not from Azure portal, so how to do that?

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-cloud-services

I have created kali linux vm using azure portal and I want to access linux vm through browser using ip address but not from azure portal
. Is it possible to access like that?

Comment: Why are you [re-asking this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69006908/creating-kali-linux-vm-and-accessing-through-web-browser)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating kali linux vm and accessing through web browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69006908/creating-kali-linux-vm-and-accessing-through-web-browser)

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK Azure Bastion only supports ssh (22) und RDP and (3389).

You can check about it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bastion/bastion-overview

Comment: Is there any other method to create vm and accessing from browser.

Comment: @TrendyGossips Probably no, as the answer author said